# How to cancat one column values into another column pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-explode

I have a dataframe, it has two columns, one is called 'PTM_loc' and another one is called 'PTM_types'

```
data['PTM_loc']
0        24
1        24;30
2        22
3        19;20;66
4        16;30;50

data['PTM_typs']
0        S
1        S
2        T
3        S;T
4        S;Y;T
```

I would like to concat (or whatever you call this action) these columns together, and get a new column like this:

```
data['PTMs']
0        S24
1        S24;S30
2        T22
3        S19;T20;T66
4        S16;Y30;T50
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with a double [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)/[`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def combine(a, b):
    a = a.split(';')
    b = b.split(';')
    return ';'.join(map(''.join, zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=a[-1])))

data['PTMs')] = [combine(a,b) for a,b in zip(data['PTM_types'], data['PTM_loc'])]

# or 
# from itertools import starmap
# data['PTMs'] = list(starmap(combine, zip(data['PTM_types'], data['PTM_loc'])))
```

Altentatively, for a pure pandas variant (just for fun, it's likely less efficient), use `ffill` to fill the missing combinations:

```
# either in rectangular form
df['PTMs'] = (data['PTM_types']
 .str.split(';', expand=True).ffill(axis=1)
 +data['PTM_loc'].str.split(';', expand=True)
).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(';'.join)

# or in long form
l = data['PTM_loc'].str.extractall('([^;]+)')
t = data['PTM_typs'].str.extractall('([^;]+)')
data['PTMs'] = (t.reindex_like(l).groupby(level=0).ffill().add(l)
                 .groupby(level=0).agg(';'.join)
                )
```

Output:

```
    PTM_loc PTM_types         PTMs
0        24         S          S24
1     24;30         S      S24;S30
2        22         S          S22
3  19;20;66       S;T  S19;T20;T66
4  16;30;50     S;Y;T  S16;Y30;T50
```

Comment: there are different lengths

Comment: @jezrael good point thanks, easy to handle ;)

Comment: Hi, it only works for the element before the first semi-comma.

Comment: @RRRRRRRR have you checked the latest version of the code (refresh your page) and provide an example if this still fail

Answer (score 1):

Something like `split`

```
s1 = data['PTM_loc'].str.split(';',expand=True)
s2 = data['PTM_typs'].str.split(';',expand=True)

data['new'] = s1.radd(s2.ffill(axis=1)).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(';'.join)
Out[20]: 
0            S24
1        S24;S30
2            T22
3    S19;T20;T66
4    S16;Y30;T50
dtype: object
```